# Как передать из выпадающего списка html переменную в django?

Tags: python, html, django

У меня есть 2 формы html

```
<form method='post' action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <select name='select'>
                 <option input value="value"> по имени (A-Z)</option>
                 <option input value="value"> по имени (Z-A)</option>
                 <option input value="value">по цене (дороже)</option>
                 <option input value="value">по цене (дешевле)</option>
             </select>
             <input type='submit' value='отсортировать' />
 </form>

 <form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p>Name:<br> <input name="name" /></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Sendtest" />
</form>
```

Мне необходимо чтобы форма с выпадающим списком передавала выбранную строку/переменную. Однако, этого не происходит. Зато 2 форма отлично передает введенные значения.

У меня есть python фаил c использованием django:

```
    x= request.POST.get("name")
    xx = request.POST.get("value","az")
```

здесь - ("value","az") ,"az" изначально задает выбранное значение при открытие html(т.к список начинается с него), однако при дальнейшей смене на убывание, возрастание, уменьшение цены переменная получает-"none". x-форма куда вводится с клавиатуры значение. хх-из формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name='select'>
             <option input value="value1"> по имени (A-Z)</option>
             <option input value="value2"> по имени (Z-A)</option>
             <option input value="value3">по цене (дороже)</option>
             <option input value="value4">по цене (дешевле)</option>
         </select>


x= request.POST.get("name")
xx = request.POST.get("select","az")
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! мучался 3 дня с попыткой понять что с ней ни так. Получается ошибка была в имени select?

Comment: Да. И обратите внимание что в функцию передается выбранное значение value.